# Css and html colour set advice

Tags: css, html

Why is the `header > section` tag, taking on the color of the section the that has been set in the CSS?

I have tried to make the `header > section` have no color but for some reason it is using the color set in the section tag.

**HTML**

```
<div id ="wrapper">
   <header>
      <section>
         <h1>This is Staffordshire</h1>
      </section>
      <nav>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="">◊ Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">◊ News Round</a></li>
            <li><a href="">◊ Contact Us </a></li>
            <li><a href="">◊ About The Town</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </header>
   <section>
      <article>
      </article>
   </section>
   <footer>
   </footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 960px;
    height: 150px;
}

section {
    display: block;
    background-color: #0FF;
    width: 960x;
    height: 600px;
}

header > section {
    border: thick groove #ff0000;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to override the CSS property set in `section`, you need to specify the specific property in `header > section`.  It looks like you just need to add `color: white;` or something, to the latter.  [Here is a Fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8etc/)

Answer (score 1):

That's because both CSS rules apply to the section.

To make the rule apply only to the second section, you can use `.wrapper > section` as selector.